# Set a JLabel text from a MySQL DB String value represent in Tamil

Tags: java, mysql, swing, unicode, jlabel

I'm trying to get a Tamil text from a database and show it in a `JLabel`.  I tried using Unicode but I can't show specific string in Tamil. It works in the `SOP("")` but it doesn't work in `jlabel12.setText(myvariable)`.

How to set a `JLabel` text with from a MySQL DB String value represent in Tamil?

Comment: provide more information, the code for example.

Comment: Please frame your question properly, not clear what you're asking for. Also provide the relevant code.

Comment: I added tamil string values to my database,now i need to show them in a label.They show in english.I tried to do using unicodes but then those values showing thier unicode values
I just want to insert tamil string values to database and show it ina jlabel

Comment: Your latest comment adds no new information.  Where is *the code?*

Comment: I cannot read code in comments.  [Edit the code into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14454103/edit).  Then select the code and click the `{}` button above the form to format it.

Comment: stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

            if (stmt.execute("select cat_name from tbl_category ")) {
                rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            } else {
                System.err.println("select failed");
            }
            while (rs.next()) {
                jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() +  rs.getString(1));

                //System.out.println(entry);
            }
This only show some symbols.not the tamil values.I have the fonts and when i insert i can show the tamil values.but cant get those using normal select qry.

Answer (score 1):

With the amount of information you provided, it's difficult to provide complete solution. Assuming you want to display Unicode characters on JLabel, try below program. It is working fine for me:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Unicode {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    UnicodeJFrame unicodeJFrame = new UnicodeJFrame();
    unicodeJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    unicodeJFrame.setSize(350, 250);
    unicodeJFrame.setVisible(true);
 } 
}

class UnicodeJFrame extends JFrame {
    public UnicodeJFrame() {
       super("Demonstrating Unicode");
       setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1));
       JLabel tamilJLabel = new JLabel("\u6B22\u8FCE\u4F7F\u7528"); //Replace this with actual Tamil unicode character
       add(tamilJLabel);

       //Remaining JLabels here
    }
}
```

From here on you can take it further. NOTE: Now it's your homework to fetch it from DB and display it, this is a hint for you.

Comment: It doesn't work outside the double quotation marks.But if I use
JLabel tamilJLabel = new JLabel(myDbValue); Its not work.
It shows "\u0069" value not the actual string value.

Comment: @user1999502, can you please post code (in your original question), so that I can have a look?

Comment: "Welcome" in Chinese? Works for me.

Comment: @trashgod, yes sample is in Chinese

Comment: Also works with "\u0BA8\u0BB2\u0BCD\u0BB5\u0BB0\u0BB5\u0BC1", which I _hope_ is also "Welcome". :-) +1 btw.

Comment: String variable ="\u0BA8\u0BB2\u0BCD\u0BB5\u0BB0\u0BB5\u0BC1";
jlabel.setText(variable);

Can anyone can get this thing done ?

Comment: Do you have a `Font` with the right glyphs?

Comment: yes it work insert using phpmyadmin but it doesn't work when i use my java code

Comment: THE RIGHT WAY
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
mysql_select_db('onlinetest',$con);

$nith = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TAMIL` (
  `data` varchar(1000) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

$nithi = "INSERT INTO `TAMIL` VALUES ('இந்தியா நாட்டின் பக்கங்கள்')";
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");